# Why is constructor called two times with only one instance?

Tags: c#, wcf, constructor

I have this WCF c# service class:

```
public partial class OhmioSVC: IOhmioSVC_Security
{
    // Porque no funciona si la variable no es estatica?
    //private static ConnectionBusiness _conn = new ConnectionBusiness();
    private ConnectionBusiness _conn;

    public OhmioSVC()
    {
        _conn = new ConnectionBusiness();
    }

    public ConnectionBusiness Conn
    {
        get
        {
            return _conn;
        }
    }

    public void Connect(string Usuario, string Password, string DataBase)
    {            
        Conn.ObtenerTicket (Usuario, Password, DataBase);                        
    }

    public List<Errores> GetErrors()
    {
        return Conn.MyErrors;            
    }        
}
```

The service has two methods: **Connect** and **GetErrores**

I use this service from the client with this code:

```
OhmioSVCClient Svr = new OhmioSVC.OhmioSVCClient();
Svr.Connect("user", "1234", "OhmioNET");
List<Errores> MyErrors = Svr.GetErrors();
```

As you can see there is one one instance of the services: Svr
But for some reason, the constructor of the services is called two times: one when I call Connect and again when I call GetErrores.

Can anybody tell why?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it's being called twice?  Are the service and client on the same machine?  Are you seeing one constructor call from the service and one from the client?

Comment: If i put a breakpoint on this line "_conn = new ConnectionBusiness();" the code reach there two times: one after Connect and one after GetErrores calls.

Comment: The only code that calls the service is my test client with the code provided

Comment: Both client and service assemblies are part of the same solution

Comment: Well, what does the [Call Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx) show for the two calls?

Comment: ericpap, try make your service class single:
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]